# InfoPath 2010, read & write to Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, infopath, infopath2010

I have an InfoPath 2010 form that I've created to submit data into an Access 2010 database. One specific element being captured is an employee ID. So, the database may have multiple records of the same employee ID.

I have a second table in the database, that contains every employee ID in one column and their name in another.

If the user is creating a record for employee ID 987, how do I add a textbox to this form that will read the corresponding name found in table 2?

Thank you,

Jeff

Comment: You need to fetch data according to employee ID You selected in Infopathform ???

Comment: Yes. I think I may need help from the access point of view as well as the infopath point of view.

Comment: I have two tables in Access: TableEmpID which is a list of Employee IDs and Names, and an TableInstance table which is a list of all of the unique issues that have been caused by the employee. Users create these reconds in TableInstance by means of an infopath form. When they are filling out the form and free-typing into the (data)EmpID text box, I want a query to run that would return the associated Name from the Table EmpID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am using this procedure in fetching data from list. Try whether its working for Ms Access

If you need to fetch data using infopath2010 then use following condition

In the `Rules` add `Action`

Under `Run these action` add `Set field value`

In field box select where fetch details wand to display (i.e which txt box)

Click `Calculted value` (fx) in value

In that click `insert field or group` and select `Show advance view`

Under field select which table you need to fetch the data

Select the field which you need to display in the selected txt box and using filter condition filter the data using `secondary table employee id=  employee id in main field`

Secondary table will visible in infopath form only if you get connected with that using `manage data connection` in infopath

Comment: Ok, Yes. I created a secondary data connection to the second table. I then created a new field not linked to an element of the database and set a rule on that textbox to match your description above. Thank you very much! I didn't know that I could query for information without using a Query field in InfoPath.